# SQL Management Studio Hangs when adding table into view or query

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Within a view or the graphical design of a query if I right click - then add table, instead of seeing the table list SQL management studio hangs and says "not responding".

Version is SQL Server 2016. Running SQL Server Management 13.0.15000.23

Any thoughts as to what may cause this ?

Answer (score 1):

These symptoms could be due to an uncommitted transaction involving DDL. Open a separate instance of SSMS and run sp_who2 to see if you observe blocking.

A word of warning - the SSMS graphical query design editor has a number of bugs. I would avoid using it.

Comment: There's 220 rows running sp_who2

Comment: @Emma, do you see any SPIDs in the BlkBy column, indicating the session is blocked by another?

Comment: No SPIDs Blkby first thing this morning and the table list did load after hanging for a while. However that will change during the day I am sure. Is there another standalone program that will be better for using with a graphical query representation ?